# CakePHP hasMany join condition using OR

Tags: php, cakephp

In model Event there is a generic event should be included with every Listing.  The listing_id of this event is '0'.  So if a Listing does not have an event.  It will show this generic event.  Also if it does have event(s)... The generic one would be included as well.

I have tried conditions using OR compound array however it will not change the correct AND to OR as shown below.

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Event' => array(
        'className'  => 'Event',
        'foreignKey' => 'listing_id',
        'dependent'  => true,
        'conditions' => array('Event.listing_id' => '0'),
    )
);
```

The above generates this SQL

```
SELECT `Event`.`id`, `Event`.`listing_id`, `Event`.`type_id`, `Event`.`when`, `Event`.`name`, `Event`.`description`, (DATE_FORMAT(`Event`.`when`, '%d')) AS `Event__day`, (DATE_FORMAT(`Event`.`when`, '%a')) AS `Event__dayN`, (DATE_FORMAT(`Event`.`when`, '%Y')) AS `Event__year`, (DATE_FORMAT(`Event`.`when`, '%h:%i %p')) AS `Event__time` FROM `events` AS `Event` WHERE `Event`.`listing_id1` = '0' AND `Event`.`listing_id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61)
```

Need to change this:

```
WHERE `Event`.`listing_id` = '0' AND `Event`.`listing_id` IN
```

TO

```
WHERE `Event`.`listing_id` = '0' OR `Event`.`listing_id` IN
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the relation to the following

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Event' => array(
        'className'  => 'Event',
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'dependent'  => true,
        'conditions' => array('or' => array(
            'Event.listing_id' => '0', 
            'Event.listing_id' => 'Listing.id'
        )),
    )
);
```

You might get away with

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Event' => array(
        'className'  => 'Event',
        'foreignKey' => 'listing_id',
        'dependent'  => true,
        'conditions' => array('or' => array('Event.listing_id' => '0')),
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A normal `find` operation in Cake [allows you to specify an `OR` condition](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions), but it seems Cake ignores this structure in the conditions of an association.

The code below would generate the query you're proposing, but the `OR` key is ignored by Cake.

```
array(
  "Event.listing_id" => 0,
  "OR" => array (
    "Event.listing_id" => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  )
)
```

Is there a specific reason you want this setup? As the conditions array of an association appears to be a bit limited, you might want to consider appending the generic event at a later point in your script. For example when you're listing the events or a single event.

Comment: because every call to this Model will need to include this.  I guess the afterFind function might be the only way to go if I modify the results before they are returned.  Also I am not generating the "IN" portion since its part of the association.

Comment: In that case `afterFind` might indeed be the second best option, as removing the superfluous `IN` portion and nesting `"Event.listing_id" => 0` in the `OR` array doesn't work either.